# How do I access the Watson Language Translator Service from Python on Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, translation, ibm-watson, machine-translation

I have a Python Flask app on my laptop that successfully accesses the Watson Language Translator on Bluemix precisely as described in the [Bluemix API Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/?python#translate)

```
from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV2 as LanguageTranslator
language_translator = LanguageTranslator(
   username='4e93f965-f1ab-407c-a502-xxxxxx',
   password='3zUExxxxxx')
translation = language_translator.translate(
   text='hello there, this is a test',
   source='en', target='fr')
print(json.dumps(translation, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

I now want to move my Python Flask app to Bluemix and access the Language Translator service totally within Bluemix. So I can no longer use `from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV2 as LanguageTranslator`

Precisely how do I access the Language Translation Service within Bluemix using the Language Translation Service credentials?

Comment: Why can't you do it the same way?  You should still be able to import from watson_developer_cloud.  The services are just out there in the cloud - they don't care where they are being accessed from, as long as the credentials are good.

Comment: Make sure you have a `requirements.txt` file in listing the packages you have installed locally. In this case `watson-developer-cloud`

Answer (score 3):

When running python on Bluemix (or most other cloud hosting providers), the standard way of defining dependencies is via a `requirements.txt` file. The bluemix server runs commands to read this file and install the dependencies listed there.

You can see complete documentation at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files but the basic version is just a file with one line like so:

```
watson-developer-cloud
```

Take a look at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=python&type=&language=python for several example python apps which use `watson-developer-cloud` and can be deployed to bluemix.